# How granular a BDD feature should be?

Tags: bdd, gherkin

Let's talk about something simple. We have a TODO list, we want to add tasks to the list. What is the feature and what is the scenario here?

a.) we are probably talking about a class or a set of services
feature: todo list
scenario1: adding a new task to the todo list
scenario2: trying to add a new task, but fail due missing task description

b.) we are probably talking about a method or a single service
feature: adding tasks to the todo list
scenario1: adding a new task
scenario2: fail due missing description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the whole concept of BDD is not related to the number of classes, methods or variables whatsoever. It's all about the **conversations** with the stakeholders.

What you're calling a feature, is probably the thing that triggers that conversation in the first place. For instance, we have a TODO list, but it's no use to anyone if it's empty. So a **feature** would be to have the **ability to add tasks into the TODO list**.

From here, the conversation begins, and most likely you'll come up with the "happy path" for your scenario:

```
Given that the TODO list is empty
When I add a new task "Buy Milk" to the list
Then the TODO list should have 1 task
And its description should be "Buy Milk"
```

Then you might start asking more questions to your stakeholder:

- Do I need to be logged in to add tasks to the TODO list?
- Do I need any permission to add tasks to the TODO list?
- Is there a maximum tasks that a TODO list can hold?
- Can I add a task with the same description as an already existing task in the TODO list?

All these questions are going to create your **scenarios**, which you'll need to describe in Gherkin with your stakeholder's help and then code it up to get them to pass.

Comment: What I meant about the class and method is the size of the feature. By the most basic implementation TodoList.add() is a method and TodoList is a class. Ofc. I know that BDD is about behavior, just it was easier to use this example implementation.

Comment: I find present-tense language to be easier to think about, eg "list has 1 task", "description is 'Buy Milk'". Also, while Gherkin is designed for this purpose, it's not necessary.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that you were only simplifying the example @inf3rno. I just wanted to highlight that very rarely you'll be mentioning classes, methods or any code design specifics when doing BDD. It's more important to figure out what "feature" you're describing (that tells you the scope) and which "scenarios" are relevant to the stakeholder (that kind of defines your tests). Thanks for accepting the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'd call them both BDD, though BDD tries to get at the purpose behind the feature, too. Anyway, "adding a task" is the feature, and doing so successfully and unsuccessfully are both scenarios. I'd probably also talk about what it means to successfully add a task (it shows up in the list, are there categories or is it a single list, is it at the top of the list or the bottom? does it have a time constraint on when it must be completed?) And I'd talk about what it means to fail to add the task (it's not in the list, probably the interface tells you that you need to add a title). Then again, why are you trying to add a task without a title? Is this a common use case? Is the title just mirroring the body? Maybe the way you want to use the list, it doesn't need a title? BDD is about the behaviour, not the implementation, so either way you go with it is fine.

Comment: Good answer, but I think hasumedic's answer suites better to my needs.